# data validation with Strings

Tags: java

I need to do some data validation to ensure that the user enters one of the 4 these 4 choices  (small,medium, large, super size)
I never did data validation with Strings,
must be there another way for this to work?

```
  public static String orderSize()
{
System.out.println("What size - small, medium, large, or super size?"); 
    String sizeChoice=input.nextLine();
    while (sizeChoice != "small" + "medium" + "large" + "super"); 
    {
        System.out.println("Must be one of the sizes listed above here.");
        System.out.println("What size - small, medium, large, or super size?");
        sizeChoice=input.nextLine();

    }
    return sizeChoice;
```

Comment: In java, "+" with Strings denotes concatenation - so your while statement is equivalent to `while (sizeChoice != "smallmediumlargesuper")`.   Also, get rid of the semicolon at the end of that `while` line - it terminates the statement - which IS the `while`, which means the block in the braces is not in the while loop at all !

Comment: If there is an answer below that most suitably answers your question, then please consider to accept that answer

Answer (score 3):

You're quite off to be honest, what I'd suggest is to first create a set holding the possible choices.

```
Set<String> choices = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("small","medium","large", "super"));
```

Then simply change your while loop condition to:

```
 while (!choices.contains(sizeChoice)){...} // while the chosen size is not in the set of choices then keep looping...
```

Comment: Good Idea. I didn't think it.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a simple easy to read switch statement (unlikely that this is an issue, but note that you [require Java 7+ to use switch with Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html))

```
boolean validated = false;
while (!validated); 
{
    switch (sizeChoice) {
        case "small":
        case "medium":
        case "large":
        case "super":
            validated = true;
            break;
        default: 
            System.out.println("Must be one of the sizes listed above here.");
            System.out.println("What size - small, medium, large, or super size?");
            sizeChoice=input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
public static int orderSize()
{
    System.out.println("What size?  \n 1. small \n 2. medium \n 3. large 4. super \n 5. cancel"); 
    int sizeChoice=input.nextInt();
    while (sizeChoice < 1 || sizeChoice > 4 ) 
    {
        System.out.println("Must be one of the sizes listed above here.");
        System.out.println("What size?  \n 1. small \n 2. medium \n 3. large 4. super \n 5. cancel");
        sizeChoice=input.nextInt();
        if(sizeChoice == 5) break;

    }
    return sizeChoice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use the [Conditional-AND](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) operator.

```
!"small".equals(sizeChoice) && !"medium".equals(sizeChoice) && !"large".equals(sizeChoice ) && !"super".equals(sizeChoice)
```

As noted by other users there is always a clever way to do the same thing. Your code also suites a `do/while` loop better than a while loop if you want to avoid repeating yourself.

```
public static String orderSize() {
    String sizeChoice = null;
    do {
        if (sizeChoice != null) {
            System.out.println("Must be one of the sizes listed.");
        }
        System.out.println("What size - small, medium, large, or super size?");
        sizeChoice = input.nextLine();
    } while (...);
    return sizeChoice;
}
```

Comment: Do not use != with Strings !

Comment: It helped a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If you do validation, I assume you have a controller. If it's only 4, I'd change the input type to an Enum, and validation will work out of the box.

The following is only to illustrate what I meant, it's dummy code, and will probably not be 100% correct.

```
@Controller  
public class ChoiceController {

   @GetMapping("/choose")
   public void choose(SizeEnum size) {
       // rest of the owl here
   }
}
```